# How can I track the moment when a new object field is added in a batch class?

Tags: apex, batch, custom-field, create-records

I have a batch class:

```
    public class DataValidation implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    private List<String> missingDates;
    
    public DataValidation(List<String> missingDates) {
        this.missingDates = missingDates;
    }
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        .....
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Exchange_Rate__c> listExistingExchangeRates){
        MetadataUtility.setNewCustomField();
        listNewRecords = CurrencyExchangeService.makeCircularRequest(missingDates);
        upsert listNewRecords;
        ...
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug('Complete!');
    }


    public class MetadataUtility {
    
    public static void setNewCustomField() {
        List<String> listNewFieldsCurrencies = CurrencyExchangeService.getNewFields();
        if(listNewFieldsCurrencies.size() > 0){
            generateField(listNewFieldsCurrencies);       
    }
    
    private static void generateField(List<String> listFieldCurrencies){
        for(String field : listFieldCurrencies){
            String metadata = '{"Metadata" : {"type" : "Currency","precision" : 18,"scale" : 1,"label" : "' +
                              + field + '","required" : false},"fullName" : "Exchange_Rate__c.'+field+'__c"}';
            createField(metadata);
        }
    }
    
    private static String createField(String metadata) {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setEndpoint('callout:ApexMDAPI/services/data/v51.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setBody(metadata);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(request);
        return res.getBody();
    }
}
```

If there is a new value in the picklist, `setNewCustomField()` adds a new field to the custom object. Next, `makeCircularRequest()` makes a request to an external service and returns a List <Exchange_Rates__с>. But sometimes I get an error. As far as I was able to find out, it is due to the fact that `setNewCustomField()` does not always have time to add a new field, and the response is already beginning to be written to the corresponding fields of my object and the system does not find a new field and throws an error. If I am right, is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

[Metadata Deployment is always asynchronous](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api/apex_metadata_api_testing) and won't be complete in time for the next statement in your batchable's `execute()`

Each metadata api deployment must [configure a callback class](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api/apex_metadata_api_updates) that will get invoked when the deployment finishes. Thus, do your follow-on processing when the callback's `handleResult` method is invoked.

I don't fully understand your business use case but you're going to have to decouple updating the metadata from any logic that depends on that updated metadata.

Comment: I have added a class code that adds a new field. I think I'm adding a new field in a different way, not like in the example on your link. Otherwise, unfortunately, I did not understand how to achieve a callback... Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: ah -- you are using the Tooling API.  So are you saying that when the HTTP `send()` returns the next statement doesn't find the newly-created field?  If you do a `describe()` on the `Exchange_Rate__c` after the Http `send()` - the new field doesn't exist?  You may need to delegate the reference to the new fields to a queueable

Comment: Yes, that's right... I also moved the link to create a new field to the queue and so far everything is working. I hope that my problem has been solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It turned out that when I start the queue, I get the error " Callout from scheduled Apex not supported." Therefore, I still won't be able to add a new field and fill it in when starting the task...

Comment: did you include implements Database.AllowCallouts on your queueable class?